# How to add a hidden note to a cart in BigCommerce

Tags: javascript, api, post, get, bigcommerce

I am working on an app for a client and am looking for a way to add a couple notes, or pieces of data, to a cart. The end goal is to be able to pull orders through the orders API and find this piece of information in it. The data contained will be strings whose values may vary from order to order. I would like to be able to add this at the cart level and prevent it from showing to the customer, before the order has been placed. What I am looking for is similar to Shopify's [cart attribute ability](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/cart/get-more-information-with-cart-attributes). Does BigCommerce have something along these lines?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting solution and sounds similar to custom fields for products when working with BigCommerce. Such a field doesn't exist for the cart page specifically, the closest being the account signup and address forms. One of these fields may fill the need you're looking for.

Comment: Apologies on the extremely late reply. I'm not sure those fields will work for me unless I am able to add custom, hidden fields and populate them through JavaScript during checkout, or the custom fields for products if I am able to do that with them.

Comment: The product ones, I assume would be modified on the product pages. I can work with this at least as a start but I would really rather run my JavaScript on both the product and checkout pages.